# Find a vector orthogonal to three other vectors

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Is it possible to find a non-zero vector Z which is perpendicular to other vectors?

Comment: If the three vectors are linearly independent then they span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. So, a vector orthogonal to these three vectors would be orthogonal to all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, hence it must be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Not in a $3$ dimensional vector space, which is what is implied by the three coordinates.  If it is a vector space over $\Bbb F$, then we have $\Bbb F^3$.

That would imply the space had dimension $\ge4$, because $\rm{det}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\2&-1&3\\1&2&3\\\end{pmatrix}=-9-3+5=-7\ne0$.

Answer (score 0):

your question has been answered but maybe for some other cases you might want to check out the Gram-Schmidt orthonormalization process!!